# How to delete the record from cds file after performing delete operation on TClietDataSet

Tags: xml, delphi, tclientdataset

I have a TClientDataset and a file with .cds extension.
I am loading the TClientDatSet by calling LoadFromFile('file_name.cds') then perform deletion operation on it. Then I save the file by calling SaveToFile method. On loading the TClientDataSet using LoadFromFile('file_name.cds') it shows that the record is deleted from the file, but when I open the file in xml or any editor it shows me the deleted record. How can I keep my file updated and clean if I perform a deletion.

Answer (score 1):

You should read in the help file about the LogChange property and MergeChangeLog method. Otherwise the ClientDataSet log changes you made, but don't alter the baseline data.